# Setting a scheduled task in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to set up wallpaper for my Windows 10 laptop. Basically, what should happen is the wallpaper should change to another (specific) image exactly on the hour. To do this, I downloaded [this](https://github.com/rwood/WallpaperChange) application.

However, I need to set a scheduled task to make it work.

If I manually run the application, then the wallpaper changes to the specified picture, no problem. But setting a task does not work. I'm very new to Windows, so I'm most likely doing it wrong.

Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

According to the Task Scheduler, the Next Run Time is `9:05:10 AM today`, and the Last Run Time is `8:05:10 today`. Both of these are right. But the program didn't run; my background is the same. For Last Run Result, it's giving me `0xE0434352`, which I'm pretty sure is not correct (it should be `0x0` if it's successful, right?)

So it looks like the task is triggering, but not running the application.

How can I fix it so it runs properly?

Comment: Shouldn't the location be filled in the the directory containing DoctorWallpaper?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include screen shots of the other tabs.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't have enough reputation to add images, sorry; someone else edited it to add that one. You can see them [here](http://imgur.com/a/FCsnm). And as for the location, I can't edit that for some reason. It won't let me paste, type, or delete the slash.

Comment: Your missing the "Action" tab :/

Comment: @DavidPostill I just uploaded it to the same album.

Comment: OK. Added. Unfortunately the extra screenshots don't show anything obviously wrong :/

Comment: @DavidPostill So I just fixed it! Not sure what I did...The event looked pretty much the same. But I set it to start at 4:00, and it just changed! Something in the application must look at what time it is and change it accordingly, if I was running it during the same hour (if it was on image three and still 3:00), nothing would have happened. But it seems to be working now!

Comment: @DavidPostill Yup! It works! I'll have to test it overnight, but it works! I'm not sure if I'm allowed to have the Task Scheduler open when the program runs. Perhaps that was the issue? Not sure, but at least it works!

Comment: why don't just use the wallpaper slideshow which was already built-in?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it "only when user is logged on."  Some things are isolated from one session to another, and "Run whether user is logged in or not" is less likely to be able to change things in the active user session.

Also try running the scheduled task with the highest privileges.

Comment: Upon trying the application again, it appears that that no longer works. So perhaps the issue now lies with the application, not the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try "for a duration of" 1 day instead of 1 hour

Comment: This is correct. "For a duration of 1 hour" means the task turns off after 1 hour, and thus will not do anything again until scheduled again 24 hrs from the initial run.

Answer (score -1):

0xE0434352 is a general .Net exception and doesn't tell you much. You might find more information in the event viewer.

When scheduling make sure you fill in "Start in(Optional)" with the path of the executable you're running, sometimes programs will crash if you don't fill this in.

Comment: What should I tell it to start in?

Comment: I added to the answer. If you're running C:\Example\Program\something.exe , the "Start in" should be C:\Example\Program\

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

What helped me was to add some random description under the name instead of leaving it blank. hope it will help :DD

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could use improvement by explaining *why/how* your solution fixes/addresses the OPs question and by adding detailed steps to implement your solution.

Comment: OP is asking about setting a scheduled task in Windows 10